Why my StreamReader blocks the program when using it with NetworkStream c#?
I am trying to make simple tcp chat but instead of NetworkStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffersize) I wanted to use StreamReader as I saw it being used in a video. Well I tried using ReadLine() and reader.Peek() per chatgpt suggestion but it doesn't seem to help.
Server:
    public static class Server
    {
        public static List<TcpClients> clients = new List<TcpClients>();
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 7777);
            listener.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                var tcpClient = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                Console.WriteLine("New client connecting.");
                clients.Add(new TcpClients(tcpClient));
                Task.Run(() => { clients.Last().HandleTcpClient(); });
            }
        }
    }
    public class TcpClients
    {
        public TcpClient tcpClient;
        public NetworkStream networkStream;
        public StreamReader reader;
        public StreamWriter writer;
        public TcpClients(TcpClient client)
        {
            this.tcpClient = client;
            this.networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            reader = new StreamReader(networkStream);
            writer = new StreamWriter(networkStream);
        }
        public void HandleTcpClient()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                string message = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(message);
                SendMessage(tcpClient, message);
            }
        }
        public void SendMessage(TcpClient sender, string message)
        {
            foreach (TcpClients client in Server.clients)
            {
                if (client.tcpClient == sender)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                client.writer.Write(message);
                client.writer.Flush();
            }
        }
    }


Client:
public static TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
public static NetworkStream ns;
public static StreamWriter writer;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    tcpClient.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, 7777);
    ns = tcpClient.GetStream();
    writer = new StreamWriter(ns);
    while (true)
    {
        var message = Console.ReadLine();
        writer.Write(message);
        writer.Flush();
    }
}


ReadLine returns the text up to the next line break. If you never write a line break, ReadLine will never return.

@jmcilhinney I changed it to a set string and still nothing on the server console

It only works if i change it form reader to:
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int size = ns.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, size));

So basically I am a dum dum and you need to use WriteLine() and ReadLine().
And it works.
